# Angular 16 how to handle Observable<Type> response in CanActivateFn implementation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular16

I want to implement `AuthGuard` using **CanActivateFn** in Angular 16 which should prevent to view some pages for unauthorized users.

`isUserLoggedIn` method in `UserService` is a get request to the backend which returns a loggedin user or throws ***UNAUTHORIZED*** exception.

I want to call `isUserLoggedIn` in `AuthGuard` and check if it throws ***UNAUTHORIZED*** exception then redirect to ***"/unauth"*** path otherwise it should return true and do nothing.

**The problem**: `isUserLoggedIn` returns `Observable<AuthorizedUser>` and **CanActivateFn** needs type `boolean`. Is there any way to do this without changing the actual GET request in backend ?

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class UserService {

 isUserLoggedIn(): Observable<AuthorizedUser> {
   const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
   return this.apiHandlerService.get<AuthorizedUser>(API_URL, headers);
 }
}
```

```js
import {CanActivateFn, Router,} from '@angular/router';
import {inject} from '@angular/core';
import {catchError, map, of} from "rxjs";

export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
    const authService: UserService = inject(UserService);
    const router: Router = inject(Router);

    return authService.isUserLoggedIn().pipe(
        map(response => {
            console.log('Response ', response);
            return true;
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            router.navigate(['/unauthorized'])
            return of(false);
        })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have done it on your own. Do you need anything else?

This is your code:

```
import {CanActivateFn, Router,} from '@angular/router';
import {inject} from '@angular/core';
import {catchError, map, of} from "rxjs";

export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
    const authService: UserService = inject(UserService);
    const router: Router = inject(Router);

    return authService.isUserLoggedIn().pipe(
        map(response => {
            console.log('Response ', response);
            return true;
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            router.navigate(['/unauthorized'])
            return of(false);
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: But I'm getting compiling error ```Type Observable<AuthorizedUser>``` is not assignable to to type ```Observable<boolean>```

Comment: @LDropl can you check this out? https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-c6uukm Let me know if your setup is similar.